# JQuery(document).ready is not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found Image Power Zoomer v1.1 is useful for my project and downloaded it. This is working fine with the code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ddpowerzoomer.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ //fire on DOM ready
 $('#myimage').addpowerzoom({
 defaultpower: 2,
 powerrange: [2,5],
 largeimage: null,
 magnifiersize: [100,100] //<--no comma following last option!
});
});
</script>

<body>
    <img id="myimage" src="ocan.png" style="width:600px; height:600px" />
</body>
```

But when I use this zoomer in the following page where I need to integrate in my project, it is not working. code is as follows(Code is more for the annotation in canvas. But easy to understand. Images not needed to be loaded for its working).I am using struts2 and tiles in my project(i am adding this thinking this may have some affect)

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ddpowerzoomer.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
     $('#original').addpowerzoom({
     defaultpower: 2,
     powerrange: [2,5],
     largeimage: null,
     magnifiersize: [100,100] /* <--no comma following last option! */
    });
    });
</script>

<style>
    #myCanvas { 
        background:url("<s:property value='resultFileName'/>") ;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    #myCanvas,#tempcanvas{ 
        cursor: pointer;
        border:1px solid black; 
        position:absolute;
        margin-left: 0px;   
        margin-bottom: 20px;                
    }

    #myCanvas:active, #tempcanvas:active { 
        cursor: crosshair;
    }       

    input[type = button],input[type = submit], select{
        width:100px;
        margin:10px 0 10px 0;
        border-radius:5px;
        font-family: Cursive;
        padding: 5px;
     }

     form, input[type = button], input[type = submit]{
        position:relative;              
     }

     input[type = image]{
        border:none;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        padding: 0;
        margin-top: 50;
        border-radius:0;
     }

</style>        
</head>     

<body style="margin-left: 200px">

<div class="form_content">

    <!-- ___________________________________Original image_______________________________ -->

    <div class="just_heading">Original Image</div>
    <img id="original" alt="Error loading the image" src="<s:property value='originalFileName'/>" width="664" height="585"/> <br><br>


    <!-- ___________________________________Result image_______________________________ -->

    <div class="just_heading">Result Image</div>
    <img id="result" src="<s:property value='resultFileName'/>" hidden="true" alt="result image" width="565" height="584"/>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="664" height="585" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
        Please use a modern browser like Firefox, Chrome, Safari
    </canvas>
    <canvas id="tempcanvas" width="664" height="585" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>

    <div>
        <canvas id="canvas2" width="664" height="585" hidden="true" style="left:600; top:10; position:obsolute;"></canvas>
        <input type="image" id="canvasImg" name="canvasImg" hidden="true"> 
        <img alt="Error loading the result" src="<s:property value='resultFileName'/>" width="664" height="585"/>
    </div>

    <!-- _______________________________Previous annotated image______________________________ -->

    <div class="just_heading">Annotated Images</div>
    <s:iterator value="annotatedImageDetails">
    <tr>
        <td><span class="just_message">Annotated by <s:property value="AnnotatedBy"/><br></span></td>
        <td><img alt="No annotated Image found" src="<s:property value="AnnotatedImageName"/>" width="664" height="585"/></td>
    </tr>
    <br><br>
    </s:iterator>
    <!--  ______________________________Script Starts here____________________________________  --> 

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: What do you see in console?

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? Simply saying 'it doesn't work' is not enough information for someone to help you.

Comment: Did you tryied to use `$(document).ready(function() { /* my code */ } );` instead ? You should also be aware of the new syntaxe to use the load event in latest JQuery version which is : `$(function() { /* my code */ } );`. Try those.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No error in console. magnifier which has to come when we hover on the image is not coming.

Comment: @Zeratops yes. it is also not working.

Comment: thats a loot of code

Comment: I know. I know that is difficult to read the code. But I don't have any choice. I don't have any expert here to discuss.  most of the code is just an annotation tool for the canvas that is present.

Comment: try to add `alert()` inside ready and check if the alerts pops up

Comment: @singhakash No alert is not poping up

Comment: try moving all the scripts at end of page

Comment: I put your code in a JSbin, and it seems to be working : http://jsbin.com/cofapedaga/1/edit?html,js,output
Maybe a browser problem? Which one are you using?

Comment: @singhakash no change

Comment: @Guillaume I saw that. but still not working here. I am using chrome.

Comment: Thanks every one . Its working. I don't know what made it work

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you switched up your script declarations in the second example.

I've checked and it seems that ddpowerzoomer.js is making use of jQuery. In fact, it is creating a jQuery function for you. You will have to instantiate jQuery before you do ddpowerzoomer.js or else it won't work.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ddpowerzoomer.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
...
```

Comment: Same as @Gauillaume, got it working locally and I just pasted your code and added my own images. Did you try turning off and on javascript? :P

Comment: That same code which he used in JSbin is working for me here in my local system when copy paste it as it is. I am wondering what is happening....!